# How to change <drupal-entity> to HTML

Tags: 8

I have a view that returns JSON-serialized content. When there is a link to a file embedded in the content, the response includes the embedded file as  tag, rather than regular HTML. My front-end app is loading the JSON response directly into the DOM, so a link to the file is obviously not appearing.

How can I modify the JSON response so that it presents a link to the file in regular HTML? Thanks.

Comment: You can achieve it by doing the following [Changing the way Serializer handles entities](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/serialization-api/changing-the-way-serializer-handles-entities). There is more indepth info here [Using Normalizers to Alter REST JSON Structure in Drupal 8](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/using-normalizers-alter-rest-json-structure-drupal-8/).